# Pointer for different char** in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

Basically I have three char**: **A, **B and **C. I want to make a pointer that shows A,B and C like this:

```
ptr[0] will be **A
ptr[1] will be **B;
ptr[2] will be **C;
```

so if I add one at ptr it will show me the next array. And if this is possible then how I can represent A[i][j] with the pointer?

Comment: `char *ptr[] = { *A, *B, *C };`, then `ptr[i][j]`?

Comment: I have the feeling that you are envisioning this as the solution to a particular problem you faced. Sometimes it is better to ask about the root problem, rather than the solution you think you want.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
char **ptr[] = { A, B, C };

char x = ptr[0][i][j];  // x is now equal to A[i][j]
```